# Entity Framework SQL Connections are not getting closed or disposed

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-4.1, sqlconnection, sqlconnection.close

I'm using Entity Framework with Repository Pattern, but we have requirement to call stored proecedure, so we ended up in creating DAL Class with EF DBContext has local private variable in DAL Class, 
private  context;

I try to instantiate  DBContext in Repository Class Constructor

```
public VRepository( IDataAccessObjectFactory daoFactory)
{
        _daoFactory = daoFactory;
        context = _daoFactory.GetEFContext<DbEntities>();           
}
```

All the Services call a method of DAL's repository class and all repository class inherits from IDisposable and implemented disposable method in repository class

```
public void Dispose()
    {
        if (context != null)
        {

            context.Dispose();
            // GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

I try to call above dispose method from service layer after completing Operation in a method, something like calling dispose method of BLL finally block to dispose the DBContext object( I'm having WEB API , WEB API -> BLL -> DAL).

Even after calling context.Dispose(), EF created Sql Connections are not getting Closed. Can Any1 suggest me right way of closing SQL connections and dispose SQL Connection. If I dont dispose, SQL connections goes to 100 which is not allowing new connections for some time or worker restart. Please let me know effective way of dispose context immediately completion of repository layer method.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense.  Why are you trying to share a context between different layers?  There is no point in this.  Just have each layer use its own context, preferably creating a new one when you need it, and destroying it when you are done.  This is how EF is designed to be used.

Comment: I have only context created in Repository layer. It is not present in my BLL..Im disposing in context in repository layer only

Comment: Closing this thread. as I have to end in creating using for every time context is been created. I moved my code of creating context from constructor to each method which create context for each call and context is created with in Using block, now I don't see sleeping connections